# Adding Magento_Catalog to Custom Module

Tags: magento2, module, magento2.2, blocks, magento2.3

I wanted to override the content of `addtocart.phtml` which is located in

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/addtocart.phtml

Now I want to modify the content of this and add this to my custom module located in

> app/code/CustomVendor/CustomModule/view/frontend/templates/product/view/addtocart.phtml

But my changes does not appear. Is my path wrong? What or where should I place the custom `addtocart.phtml` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to override in to your theme to below path:

> **/var/www/html/magentoroot/app/design/frontend/Vendor/customtheme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/addtocart.phtml**

if you make addtocart.phtml in your custom module like

> app/code/CustomVendor/CustomModule/view/frontend/templates/product/view/addtocart.phtml

you need to change catalog_product_view.xml layout too

Answer (score 1):

if you want to override core template in your custom module then you have to create that particular layout file and write a code of "setTemplate" as below:

**catalog_product_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart">
            <action method="setTemplate">
           <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Package_Module::product/view/addtocart.phtml</argument>
       </action>
    </body>
</page>
```

Then you can create a file inside your module according to a path defined in

```
Package/Modeule/view/frontend/templates/product/view/addtocart.phtml
```